# Java Appletでセレクトボックス付きのダイアログ作成

Tags: java

以下のサイトでJava Appletではダイアログ表示ができることがわかりました。
http://syunpon.com/programing/java/sample/applet/dialogsample.shtml

現在このダイアログにセレクトボックスを設置して値を取得したりしたいのですがどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんなコードはいかがでしょう。
[コードの参照元](http://www1.megaegg.ne.jp/~yasu/Programmer%27s%20Page/swing/JOptionPane/JOptionPane.html)

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DialogSample extends JApplet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static Container c;
  public void init() {
    c = getContentPane();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("未入力です");
    c.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    String selectvalues[] = {"10代", "20代", "30代", "40代","50以上"};
    Object ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(c, "あなたの年齢？", 
      "年齢", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
      null, selectvalues, selectvalues[0]);

    if (ans == null){
      label.setText("取消されました");
    }else{
     label.setText("あなたの年齢は" + (String)ans + "ですね");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。思っていた通りのことができました。